# Firebase Firestore Android How to Create a document with Boolean fields onClick

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a document in Firestore that creates Boolean fields once the button is clicked, I have used the code bellow but so far it only creates the document with no fields.

```
Boolean False = false;
```

```
registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Boolean vValue = False.booleanValue();

                                userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                DocumentReference documentReference2 = ffStore.collection("user_progress").document(userID);
                                Map<String,Object> user2 = new HashMap<>();
                                user.put("introOption_1_clicked", vValue);
                                documentReference2.set(user2).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Log.i("Message", "onSuccess: user Profile is created2 " + userID);
                                    }
                                });
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a map for document data called `user2`:

```
Map<String,Object> user2 = new HashMap<>();
```

But then you populate some other map called `user`, and we can't see where it's defined:

```
user.put("introOption_1_clicked", vValue);
```

Then you use the empty `user2` map to create the document, which will have no fields:

```
documentReference2.set(user2)
```

I suspect you meant to populate the `user2` map instead of this unknown `user` map.

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed the issue. I will be more observant next time.